# Javascript - Audio elements not playing on iOS

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I'm trying to have audio elements play whenever I turn the page of a book. The audio element only plays for the first page of the book, but when I turn the page and fire a function `bookTurned()` the audio doesn't play on the rest of the other pages turned. This issue is only happening on iOS as on every other web browser the audio is played accordingly. I've already seen that this is quite a common problem on iOS, but I haven't been able to figure out what I need to do to loop around this issue and make it work. Can someone kindly explain what would need to be done in order to have this work on iOS?

EDIT: On iOS I'm getting the following error:
`NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.`

```
async bookTurned(event, page, pageObject) {
        // Set first page turn
        if (!bookTimer) {
            bookTimer = new Timer();
        }

        // Determine direction
        const direction = page > prevPage ? DIRECTION.RIGHT : DIRECTION.LEFT;

        // Update turn index
        currTurnIndex = convertPageNumberToTurnIdx(page);

        // Play audio corresponding to the two pages we just turned to.
        await BOOK_AUDIO_PLAYER.play(currTurnIndex + 1);

        // Recalc max pages since turn js dynamically renders pages
        const currMaxPages = calcMaxPages();
        if (currMaxPages > maxPages) {
            maxPages = currMaxPages;
        }
}
```

`BOOK_AUDIO_PLAYER` handles the audio

Comment: If you were to use a console log in `bookTurned` does it log every time?

Comment: Yes it does log every time.

Comment: May you add a try/catch around `BOOK_AUDIO_PLAYER.play` and see if the promise is being rejected?

Comment: The thing is that it actually works perfectly fine on a web browser. I'm only experiencing this problem when I head over to iOS and test it there.

Comment: Does `BOOK_AUDIO_PLAYER.play` throw when on iOS?

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood you for a second there. Yes, I am indeed getting an error on iOS, thanks for suggesting that. The error states: "NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission."